# Gimp 2.10: Why are the values in the alpha mask always gamma corrected?

Tags: gimp

Usecase:
Gimp 2.8.16:

1. create an image
2. add an alpha channel
3. transfer alpha to alpha mask
4. write RGB(100, 100, 100) in the alpha mask --> apply the mask
5. Result: RGBA(x,x,x,100) when applying the mask

Color picker showing the rgba values:
[image: color picker showing the rgba values]

Gimp 2.10.6:

1. create an "Precision:8bit" "Gamma:Linear light" image
2. add an alpha channel
3. transfer alpha to alpha mask
4. write RGB(100, 100, 100) in the alpha mask
5. Result: RGBA(x,x,x,34) when applying the mask

[image]

34 is the gamma corrected value. To get RGBA(x,x,x,100) i need to write RGB(167,167,167) in the alpha mask. Which is (100/255)^(1/2.2)*255.

How can i write whatever value in the alpha mask and get that as alpha in my image without it ever being gamma corrected?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is known by the gimp developers.
See: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/2519